# Image opened in adobe photoshop shows wrong color

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, images

I have opened an image in Adobe Photoshop, showing a green football lawn.

[image]

In Photoshop, this image is displayed with a violet color. Every picture I open has not it´s original colors.
Settings are:

- Image Mode: RGB Color; 8 Bits/Channel

This is what my workbench looks like:

[image]

If I select the lasso tool (or similar tools) and hover over the image, **it gets it´s original color**.

**Update**
The problem has disappeared since a few days. I have changed nothing at all...

Comment: It seems as though your colors are being inverted. Does it look normal if you invert them after opening? (CRTL+I)

Comment: Then the image gets blue!

Comment: @AGuyCalledGerald Take a look at the answers on http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3460/colors-change-in-photoshop-when-copying-a-selection-from-one-document-into-a-new

Comment: Did you check the mode? (Image > Mode)

Comment: @yisela, RGB Color, 8 Bits/Channel

Comment: I have the same problem only in this image viewer.. the other viewers show the image properly.. it's only this one.. so changing the monitor settings will screw up the others.. so what other answer is there?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Different colors and shadows when opening an image in photoshop and after saving the picture](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/58447/different-colors-and-shadows-when-opening-an-image-in-photoshop-and-after-saving)

Comment: Maybe the problem disappeared because you didn't resave the image with the same embedded profile. @Adrienne I don't know if you mean Photoshop by image viewer but colors can be horribly wrong when viewing a CMYK image on some viewer. If the issue is with Photoshop, have a look at the link above. Photoshop needs to be "set up" properly before you use it, it's not always perfect out of the box!

Answer (score 2):

Recalibrate your monitor.

Chances are very high that your monitor color profile has become corrupt.

Comment: Does this mean, that by using another monitor the problem should be solved?

Comment: No. The monitor itself doesn't matter. What matters is the color profile Photoshop is reading to display the image. Recalibrating your monitor should be easily possible via the control panels or system preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Double check display card settings and driver. The screenshot of the side menu looks different.

Comment: how to, please?