# Different colors and shadows when opening an image in photoshop and after saving the picture

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, color-profile, shadows

I am working on Photoshop CS6 and i face the following problem.

When I open a jpg file on Photoshop CS6, the image appears to be much more dark than the original jpg.

If I start editing the picture in order to be brighter and then I try to save to a new jpg, then the result I get is completely different again: The new picture is bleached...

I try to open it with a different Photoshop version (CS5) but the problem still remains.

Comment: Calibrate your monitor and ensure you've got color settings correct for the application.

Comment: The monitor is brand new and it came already calibrated. the color settings are already corrected. the thing than concerns me is that maeby there is a problem, or any wrong setting with my graphics card. do you think this may be pissible?

Comment: In my experience there's no such thing as a properly calibrated monitor out of the box. They **all** have to be calibrated.

Comment: check the color space--is it RGB or CMYK

Answer (score 2):

The way you explain your issue, it seems like you have an embedded [color profile](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/creativesuite/cs/using/WSBB0A8512-8151-408c-9F79-4A9E9E3BA84C.html) in your image and your preferences are set to keep these profiles.

When you do a "save for web", it usually removes that profile so the image is lighter. And if you do a normal "save as" and look at the JPG in a browser or a software that doesn't do color management, it will look lighter too because it ignores that profile. But when you open that image in Adobe Photoshop, there's a "tag" attached to the image and it tells Photoshop to adjust the colors of that picture with specific values. That's probably why you see the image differently. You need to remove that profile if you don't need it.

> I recommend you learn more about color profiles, this answer is just a
> very brief explanation of the issue and there's other things you need
> to consider when ignoring, using or embedding color profiles!

## Example with a profile applied to an image:

The one on the right has a profile embedded, the one on the left doesn't. I used a very dark profile to show the difference.

[image: Color profiles and none]

## You need to go in your color management settings

In Photoshop, go in the menu "edit" and select "color settings."

You have some options there, and **you should read about color profiles** to see what's better for you.

You can set the color profile management to OFF in the "color management policies" section.

You can also checked the boxes that will show a warning when this happens and let you choose if you want to convert the color profile or discard it.

[image: Color management policies]

If there's a color profile when you open an image, it will show you a warning.

[image: Warning embedded profile]

## Other option

You can also **uncheck** the "Embed color profile" when you do a "save as" of your JPG, and re-open it.

[image: Save as]

---

## Extra info about this:

[What should I do regarding color profile when designing for the web?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/9208/what-should-i-do-regarding-color-profile-when-designing-for-the-web)

Answer (score 0):

Try using wscRGB in the Assign Profile section.

Answer (score -5):

Found this video for a quick FIX. Its roughly a 1 minute video that shows how to fix the color profile issue so images show up properly in Adobe Photoshop. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aB_xN2kLVCE

Comment: Hi ShayeRyan, could you please explain a bit more what we'll find behind the link you provide and why it answers the question? That way, your answer is still of value in case the link breaks at a later time. Link rot is the main reason we really dislike link-only answers here. Thanks for your effort and keep contributing!